# Error in declaring a CHARACTER variable: Is this a gfortran bug or my own error?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

The following fortran program produces an error on compilation. I am using gfortran within gcc 6.2.0.
A minimal program that produces the error is the following:

```
PROGRAM test_len
    CHARACTER (LEN=*), DIMENSION(2), PARAMETER :: chs = &
       [ CHARACTER (LEN=LEN("longest string")) :: "string1", &
        "longer string" ]

    WRITE(*,*) chs

END PROGRAM test_len
```

The compilation does not produce an executable and the error I get is the following:

```
f951.exe: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
```

Is this a known gfortran bug (perhaps already solved in subsequent versions)? Or is it an error in my code?
The problem seems to be in the declaration of `chs`. Specifically, when I replace `(LEN=LEN("longest string"))` by `(LEN=14)` the program compiles fine and behaves as expected--i.e., it prints `string1 longer string`.

Comment: How do you compile? I've just copy-and-pasted your code in a `temp.f90` file and successfully compiled it with `gfortran temp.f90 -o temp`. The output is `string1       longer string`.

Comment: @Enrico Maria De Angelis : Enrico: I work in MS Windows 7 (64-bit) and use a package called fortran tools which calls the gfortran compiler from Code::Blocks. But I think this is unlikely to make much difference, as Code::Block passes the ascii file to the gfortran compiler. Although I will try compiling on a command window. Possibly more important is the gfortran version: I use the one in gcc 6.2.0. Please, let me know which gfortran version you use--if it is a bug it may have been fixed already.

Comment: "Internal compiler error" is always a compiler bug (unless somehow triggered by something in the environment, such as a memory corrupter.) It doesn't matter if your code is valid or not. I don't see any problems with your code. I haven't kept up with gcc versions, but see if an install of the latest one resolves the problem. I'm also intrigued by the libbacktrace message, though I don't know if that's usually seen with these errors.

Comment: @JEA, I use 9.2.0 at the moment.

Comment: You need a much newer version of gfortran.  6.2 is ancient.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. My conclusion is that this was a bug in gfortran 6.2.0 (the one I am using) but it has been corrected since. I guess, the obvious solution is to upgrade my version of gfortran.

Comment: I seem to favour using character*(*) if I do not have a defined length...

Comment: @Holmz How would that be supposed to help? `CHARACTER (LEN=*)` is the same thing.

Comment: @Vladimir Well maybe we have a clue here? I always use fixed length in the main, and in cases where the subroutine needs variable I use character*(*)..  so I would use fixed max length or an allocatable in the main program... usually I use (LEN=128) and sometimes 256 to 2048... depending if I am barking out a message or reading a .csv string.

Comment: @Holmz That's like telling a patient who has a pain the neck when he turns his head - Do not turn your head! The program is clearly a simplified [mcve] about solving a specific issue with a very modern Fortran feature. A very nice *minimal* example in fact, many peoole should come and see how it is supposed to be done. There is a specific issue at hand and that one should be resolved. It was clearly a defect in the compiler that was later fixed.